# Python for loop for list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing some integer values.

My list is `l = [5,10,15,25,30,45]`.

I want to write a program that the values in list is between 5 to 35

```
list1 = [15,35]
list2 = ['Height','Weight','5','10','25','30','40']
res = [int(ele) if ele.isdigit() else ele for ele in list2]
print([ x for x in res if type(x)==int ])
```

this is the code that I written,now I want to compare list 1 and list 2 , then print values in list 2 of range in the first list

Comment: Better if you try to develop this and post if you have any problems or question

Comment: Please post your code and let us know what does not work.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [5,10,15,25,30,45]
for x in l:
  if(x>=5) and (x<=35):
     print(x)
```

for every number in the array print if it's between and including 5 and 35.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [5,10,15,25,30,45, 35]
a = [i for i in l if 5 <= i <= 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in l:
    if(i>35):
      break
    print(i)
```

Please try this for the list.

Use break whenever you want to out form the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

```
>>> l = [5,10,15,25,30,45]
>>> result = [i for i in l if i in range(5,36)]
>>> result
[5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
```